# Поиск тега по значению его атрибута и скрытие/отображение доп.блока при активном radio

Tags: javascript

Блок id="passport" по умлочнаию невидим.
Задача - сделать блок с id="passport" видимым, если radio с атрибутом value='65' выбрано(активно), если выбрали другой radio, то скрыть блок с id="passport".

Застопорился в синтаксисе, не находит value='65'. А может быть и логика не верная в данном решении задачи. Прошу помощи, правильный ли ход мысли в решении задачи?

```js
var subtree = document.getElementById('frameDelivery');//поиск в поддереве элемента с ID frameDelivery
var elems = subtree.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );// находим всех потомков input и записываем в коллецию.
//далее, осуществляем перебор элементов с условием, - ищем элемент с атрибутом value='65', как только нашли выполняем первое условие.
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
if (elems[i].getAttribute('value', 65) == 65) {
  
 /*if(true){
    //первое условие: делаем снова проверку, активно ли данное radio, если да (checked="checked"), то выполнить код - назначить событие. Где, делаем видимым скрытый блок.
 }
  else {
   //если выбрали другой radio, то скрыть блок с id="passport"
  }
 */
 
  }
 else {
  alert('Элемент не найден!');
 }
  

}
```

```css
#passport {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups-form">
    <div class="frame-label" id="frameDelivery">
    <span class="title">Способ получения</span>
        <div class="frame-form-field check-variant-delivery">
            <div class="frame-radio">

                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="63">
                    </span>

                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Самовывоз</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="63">Подробнее</span>


                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="66">
                    </span>
                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Доставка курьером</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="66">Подробнее</span>


                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="64">
                    </span>
                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Доставка с монтажом</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="64">Подробнее</span>


                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="65">
                    </span>

                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Транспортной компанией</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="65">Подробнее</span>


            </div><!--end frame-radio-->
        </div><!--frame-form-field-->
    </div><!--frame-label-->
</div><!--groups-form-->

<div class="groups-form" id="passport">
    <div class="frame-label">
        {echo ShopCore::app()->CustomFieldsHelper->setRequiredHtml('<span class="must"></span>')->setPatternMain('pattern_custom_field')->getOneCustomFieldsByName('passportSeriesNumber','order')->asHtml()}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если это нужно именно в контексте вашего кода, то сделать это можно так:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName( 'deliveryMethodId' );

var el_checked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  if (elems[i].value == 65 && elems[i].checked) {
    el_checked = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (el_checked) {
  document.getElementById('passport').style.display = 'block';
} else {
  document.getElementById('passport').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Но обычно на нужные `<input type="radio">` устанавливается обработчик события, который проверяет `this.value` и в зависимости от значения совершает нужные действия.

**UPD:** Для того, чтобы код отрабатывал при переключении `radio` код необходимо изменить таким образом.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName( 'deliveryMethodId' );

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.value == 65) {
      document.getElementById('passport').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('passport').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А у Вас в условии две проверки, что в данной ситуации избыточно. Да еще переопределение переменных...)

Comment: Две проверки в условии для того, чтобы определить, что у текущего элемента нужное значение `value` и что этот элемент выбран (см. вопрос). И где вы увидели переопределение переменных?

Comment: Подскажите, проверяю ваш код, а он не срабатывает. Ошибок в отладчике Хром тоже нет. Не могу понять что не так: https://jsfiddle.net/Delat/m2L00ybv/116/

Comment: @ikar, он срабатывает при загрузке страницы. Как я написал в ответе, это решение именно в контексте вашего кода. Если вы хотите, чтобы изменения происходили при переключении ваших `radio`, то нужно вешать на них обработчики событий и код, соответственно, тоже нужно будет менять.

Comment: @ikar, дополнил ответ вариантом, который работает по клику.

Answer (score 0):

Я немного не так сделал)

```js
var subtree = document.getElementById('frameDelivery');//поиск в поддереве элемента с ID frameDelivery
var elems = subtree.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );// находим всех потомков input и записываем в коллецию.
//далее, осуществляем перебор элементов с условием, - ищем элемент с атрибутом value='65', как только нашли выполняем первое условие.
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
 var t = elems[i].getAttribute('value');
if (t == 65) {
    alert("Да вот же он");
    break;

 /*if(true){
    //первое условие: делаем снова проверку, активно ли данное radio, если да (checked="checked"), то выполнить код - назначить событие. Где, делаем видимым скрытый блок.
 }
  else {
   //если выбрали другой radio, то скрыть блок с id="passport"
  }
 */
 
  }
 else {
  alert('Элемент не найден!');
 }
  

}
```

```css
#passport {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="groups-form">
    <div class="frame-label" id="frameDelivery">
    <span class="title">Способ получения</span>
        <div class="frame-form-field check-variant-delivery">
            <div class="frame-radio">

                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="63">
                    </span>

                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Самовывоз</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="63">Подробнее</span>


                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="66">
                    </span>
                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Доставка курьером</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="66">Подробнее</span>


                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="64">
                    </span>
                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Доставка с монтажом</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="64">Подробнее</span>


                <div class="frame-label">
                    <span class="niceRadio b_n">
                        <input type="radio" required name="deliveryMethodId" value="65">
                    </span>

                    <div class="name-count">
                        <span class="text-el">Транспортной компанией</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span onclick="popupme(this); return false;" class="modal" data-type="delivery" data-target="65">Подробнее</span>


            </div><!--end frame-radio-->
        </div><!--frame-form-field-->
    </div><!--frame-label-->
</div><!--groups-form-->

<div class="groups-form" id="passport">
    <div class="frame-label">
        {echo ShopCore::app()->CustomFieldsHelper->setRequiredHtml('<span class="must"></span>')->setPatternMain('pattern_custom_field')->getOneCustomFieldsByName('passportSeriesNumber','order')->asHtml()}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код 3 раза напишет "Элемент не найден!" и 1 раз "Да вот же он"

Comment: @Pyramidhead ну так, наверное, на странице только 1 инпут со значение 65)

Comment: Да, но цикл у вас от этого не прервётся. Просто выполните ваш код.

Comment: @Pyramidhead, у человека была проблема - он не мог найти нужный инпут.  Я ему помог найти его. Я так понимаю - он и сам дальше знает, что делать. Если так принципиально наличие слово `break`, то я его напишу. Только толку от этого - если искомый инпут все равно последний)

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки! Попробую доделать всё сам. Но то что есть уже ответ, тоже хорошо:-)